# Django with pandas

Tags: python, html, django, pandas, dataframe

I want display dataframe with info from pandas df.info()
this display to output in the command prompt but in html
display None !!

Views.py

```
my_file = pd.read_csv(filename, engine='python')
data = pd.DataFrame(data=my_file)

   mydict = {
    "data": data.to_html(),
    "dinfo": data.info(),
    }
```

```html
<div><h6 class="major">Data </h6>{{data|safe}}</div>
<div><h6 class="major">Data Info:</h6>{{dinfo|safe}}</div>
```

Comment: Share the whole view function or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StringIO`:

```
import io

# Redirect output to a buffer
info = io.StringIO()
data.info(buf=info)
info.seek(0)

mydict = {
    "data": data.to_html(),
    "dinfo": info.read(),
}
```

**Update**

> Is there a way to appear in a coordinated way on the page?

```
# pip install markdown
import markdown

mydict = {
    "data": data.to_html(),
    "dinfo": markdown.markdown(info.read()),
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
But is there a way to appear in a coordinated way on the page?

Comment: You can enclose the output of `dinfo` into `<code>{{dinfo|safe}}</code>` or use `markdown` (but it's not perfect).